# Слово вида {$goods.phone_1} присвоить переменной(готов заплатить)

Tags: php, переменные

Есть слово из базы MSYQL выводиться в {$goods.phone_1} На HTML странице все отлично, значение видно и в Javascript тоже присваивается, а вот в php нет.
Реализация любым удобным способом!

Если делаю так

```
 <? $string = "{$goods.phone_1}"; if (isset($string[1])){?>
```

определяет как заполнена мне кажется все из-за $

```
<? $string = "{$goods.phone_1}";

if (isset($string[1])){?>
<div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_1|escape}</div></span>

<?}else{?><?}?>
```

Все это нужно для Если {$goods.phone_1} не пустое то показать **<span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_1}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_1|escape}</div></span>**

Весь код странницы----------------------------------------------------------------

```
{include file=header.html}

{include file=top.html}

<div id="content">
    <div id="left">
        {include file=left.html}
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        {include file=goodsinfo.html}

        <a name="module">
        <ul class="user_menu">
            <div class="ornament1"></div>
            <div class="ornament2"></div>
            <li><a class="normal" href="{url app=goods&id=$goods.goods_id}#module"><span>Описание товара</span></a></li>
            <li><a class="active" href="{url app=goods&act=comments&id=$goods.goods_id}#module"><span>Основные характеристики</span></a></li>
                    </ul>

<!-- Вывод информации с модуля Основные характеристики -->
                                <!--/*-------------Мобильные устройства-----------------------------------*/ -->
<span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_1}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_1|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_2}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_2|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_3}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_3|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_4}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_4|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_5}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_5|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_6}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_6|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_7}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_7|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_8}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_8|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_9}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_9|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_10}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_10|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_11}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_11|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_12}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_12|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_13}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_13|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_14}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_14|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_15}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_15|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_16}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_16|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_17}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_17|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_18}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_18|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_19}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_19|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_20}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_20|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_21}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_21|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_22}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_22|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_23}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_23|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_24}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_24|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_25}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_25|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_26}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_26|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_27}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_27|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_28}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_28|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_29}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_29|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_30}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_30|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_31}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_31|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_32}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_32|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_33}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_33|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_34}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_34|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_35}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_35|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_36}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_36|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_37}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_37|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_38}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_38|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_39}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_39|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_40}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_40|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_41}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_41|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_42}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_42|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_43}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_43|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_44}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_44|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_45}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_45|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_46}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_46|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_47}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_47|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_48}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_48|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_49}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_49|escape}</div></span>
                    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_50}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_50|escape}</div></span>

                <dt><a href="{$app_data.app_url}">{$app_data.app_name}</a></dt>

                <dd>{$item}</dd>

            </dl>

        <!--{/if}-->
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

{include file=footer.html}
```

Comment: При $string = '{$goods.phone_1}' Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

$string = "{\$goods.phone_1}"; Тоже самое

Comment: Интересует почему <? $string = "{$goods.phone_1}"; в таком виде не присваивает значение переменой. Ответ про конструкцию поступил.

Comment: Потому что это {$goods.phone_1} парсить ваш шаблонизатор и генерирует какой то там php код

Answer (score 1):

```
{if $goods.phone_1|escape|strlen > 2}
    <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_1|escape}</div></span>
{/if}
```

Как то так, что за шаблонизатор вы используете?

Answer (score 0):

http://tsya.ru

```
$string = "{\$goods.phone_1}";
$string = '{$goods.phone_1}';
```

> isset($string[1])

Эээээ, это очень странная конструкция. Проще как минимум писать `if ($string)`, если я правильно понимаю ее предназначение.

Comment: @Fike, isset($string[1]) проверка есть ли в строке второй по счету символ. Представьте что string -> своеобразный массив состоящий из элементов char.

Comment: Я вчера показывал ТСу как проверить наличие символа...

Comment: @avengerweb, если б я этого не знал, меня бы стоило закопать, а в качестве эпитафии выбрать три единственные более-менее адекватные строчки моего кода. Автор, очевидно, интересуется не первым символом, а наличием контента в строке.

Comment: @d_i_m99, вы не присвоите переменную таким образом. Как я понимаю у вас шаблонизатор, скорее всего - smarty...

Comment: @Fike, у меня появилась долька сомнения в вас, if ($string) условие не выполниться, если переменная $string == false или == null в любом другом случае(есть ли там символы или нет и переменная определена) условие выполнится.
Что касательно isset($string[1]) оно укажет если ли в строке символа, а отсюда вывод пустая она или нет.

Бывает шарики за ролики закатываются... :)

Comment: @avengerweb
1. http://tsya.ru
2. http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

> При преобразовании в boolean, следующие значения рассматриваются как FALSE:

> само значение boolean FALSE
> integer 0 (ноль)
> float 0.0 (ноль)
> **пустая строка, и строка "0"**

Comment: Соглашусь что НЕ очень хорошо разбираюсь. Готов отблагодарить за помощь на пиво:)